# Using a FutureBuilder with one future depends on the results on the other future

Tags: flutter, dart

The way I structured my firebase firestore and storage is that once I get a uid of an item in firestore, I take that id to my storage and retrieve a list of downloadUrls to display images. so retrieving the downloadUrls will depend on the uid, two of which are async calls with a dependency.

All of this is for purpose of displaying a very standard card widget with a picture and description at the bottom.

In my `FutureBuilder` `future` parameter, I tried using `Future.wait` api but then I don't know how I can pass the information retrieved from one future onto the next future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Future.wait` is not meant for this purpose. It's meant for *independent* futures. If you have two futures and one needs the return value of the other to start, wrap them both into one future:

```dart
//First future for uid
Future<String> uid() async {
  return id;
}

//Second future for URL
Future<String> downloadURL(String uid) async {
  //Use the uid and get the download URL future
}

//Wrapper to combine them
Future<String> combined() async {
  final uid = await uid();
  return downloadUrl(uid);
}
```

Then you can pass the `combined` future to your `FutureBuilder`.